# Only want to show assigned wordpress category

Tags: arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, categories, custom-taxonomy

I am building a education platform within wordpress, but i am having difficulties getting the categories only to show the user  assigned categories in the filter.

I am using ACF Pro to assign my custom categories to the users.

And here i get the terms assigned to the user.

```
$uid = get_current_user_id();
$departments = get_terms( array('departments'), 'user_'.$uid );
```

In this line i am looping the categories:

```
foreach ($departments as $value) {
                if(!in_array($value->term_id, $departments)){

          echo '<input id="switch-demo'. $value->term_id .'" type="checkbox" data-filter="'. $value->term_id .'" class="filter-check '. $value->term_id .'" value="'. $value->term_id .'" name="departments[]" >';
                echo '<label for="switch-demo'. $value->term_id .'" class="filter '.$value->slug.'">'. $value->name .'</label>';

                // echo $value->name;
            }
        }
```

For some reason it is showing all categories that are currently in my post type "Courses".

But i want to make sure that y category field is only showing categories that are assigned to the user.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`get_terms` doesn't take any `user_.$uid` parameter. Only thing you should pass to `get_terms` should be the arguments array.

For ACF, to get a field value you will need to use `the_field` or `get_field` functions.

```
$uid = get_current_user_id();
$departments = get_field( 'departments', 'user_'.$uid );
```

[More details on how to get values from user using ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/)